# phpexcel format value on import

Tags: phpexcel

I'm working on laravel project that takes in excel file to grab certain columns from it

```
 $sheetData = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file)->getActiveSheet();
        $hi_row = $sheetData->getHighestRow();
        $hi_col = $sheetData->getHighestColumn();
        $sheetData = $sheetData->toArray(null,false,true, true);
```

there are some files that have different formatting on cells where in my toArray() function if i do null, false, true, true) dates comes in fine but on some excel files currency value comes up with ? in it, if i set third true condition to false, than currency comes out fine but on some excel files data gets turn into random integer. so is there any way to set all cells to general on import? or if i choose to leave it at toArray(null, false,true, true) can i set the currency column to general or something so i won't get those ?s

Comment: What charset are you using to display the results of this?

Comment: i believe using utf-8

Comment: What type of datafile is this? Is it a real Excel File (BIFF-format or OfficeOpenXML)? Those are explicitly converted to UTF-8? Or is it a CSV file, that may not be UTF-8?

Comment: i ran getStyle('O14')->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode() on three different xls i have on some date column format is mm-dd-yyyy, on others its General, on some currency column format is ""$"?,??0.00" and others currency column format is General. so I'm trying to figure out way to grab the data from these variations of file.

Comment: yes they are real xls files

Comment: General format won't give you anything special, that should simply appear as an unformatted number.... `"$"?,??0.00"` should use a `$` sign for the currency code, with a comma for thousands separator and rounded to 2dp

Comment: yes but my question is how can i grab the data from these different files so when i store it in database I'm not getting random values. would the best option to be just leave it as is and just remove the ? with str_replace() ?

Comment: If you're getting random values, then you've identified a major bug in PHPExcel; one I've never seen before.... computers don't generally do random.... but you should be storing raw values rather than formatted numbers in a database anyway; numbers should be stored as numbers, not as strings with currency codes and thousands separators

Comment: If you're seeing general format, and a value like `$1,000.00` then that data has been entered into MS Excel as a string, and not as a number with a currency format mask.... I'd expect to see exactly that value whether you used toArray() with or without formatting

Comment: ok so when i read the the file how can i grab the raw values?

Comment: `toArray()` with the third argument set to false (the default) should return the raw (unformatted) values.... if you still see currency values with a currency code and/or comma separators, then that raw value is a string, not a number in MS Excel..... and PHPExcel won't help you with changing that, because PHPExcel is simply returning the actual raw value that is stored in that cell, that's something that needs doing in standard PHP

Comment: And no data will get turned into a random integer..... are you talking about date/time values?

Comment: yes i can handle the string part later as long as I'm not getting ?s, and it does work fine when i set the third argument to false, but then in some files it turns dates into integer

Comment: If they're stored correctly as dates in MS Excel, and an appropriate format mask applied, then they are numbers.... they're an MS Excel serialized timestamp..... PHPExcel provides `ExcelToPHP()` and `ExcelToPHPObject()` methods in `PHPExcel_Shared_Date` that will convert that MS Excel serialized timestamp to a Unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object respectively, and you can then use standard PHP date functions (or DateTime object methods) to do what you want with them